# Positioning an element relative to height of next element

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<span class="targetIcon"/>${targetInfo}
```

Here, the class `targetIcon` is:

```
.targetIcon:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f56f";
    font-size: 2em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

When value of `targetInfo` is: `Drag and drop a file or click to browse`, this resolves as:

[image]

However, when `targetInfo` is a little long and thus moves to new line, this resolves as:

[image]

The second image above (multi-line) is correct.

However, in the first image, the text is not centered after the icon. How can I position the text at the center of the icon?

I want the positioning of both elements to be decided based on whether the text is single line or multi-line.

Comment: use flexbox to center and you will get what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
.targetIcon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.targetIcon:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f56f";
    font-size: 2em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="targetIcon">Drag and drop a file or click to browse</span>
```